# TextArea JavaFX wrapText adds line breaks

Tags: javafx, textarea, word-wrap

I have a TextArea with the wrapText activated because I need to fully visualize a line with 300 characters. But when I copy and paste the textArea content into a Notepad, I see that it added line breaks.

Does anyone know if this can be changed?

I need to recover the same line with 300 characteres when I copy and paste, without the line breaks

Comment: If you copy and paste into Notepad++, it's easy to remove all the new line characters.

Comment: Whoops, ignore my last comment. This is an issue of Notepad, not an issue of your program. I strongly recommend not using this editor anyways; Notepad++, PSPad and even Firefox's JavaScript environment editor get it right...

Comment: @LuZcila here is my TextArea remover     String line = txaInput.getText();
    line = line.replaceAll("[-@#$%&/0-9()+=,!.?<>:|_*]","");
    strArray = line.split("\\s");

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it's not an issue of Notepad, because I can see that the line breaks are already in the textArea, before copying.

Comment: I can use that removing code if I override the copy method, but I think that's not the best option, there's probably a way to avoid the line breaks... or is it an issue of TextArea??